# When I try to use the """ thing for print, i get a syntax error

Tags: python

Okay so I am really bored and decided to have my computer type a poem on my screen. I copied and pasted lyrics onto my screen like so:

```
import time
import sys

def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write( '%s' % c )
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.09999)

delay_print 
"""
lyrics
words
blah
blah
blah

"""
```

But when I paste the code in I get a syntax errors because there are apostrophes in it. I don't want to remove them because it basically takes half of the coolness out of it in a way. Is there any way around it?

Comment: Btw, `"` is a quote, not an apostrophe.  A `'` is an apostrophe.

Comment: I know, but in the lyrics they are apostrophes. Thats what is causing the errors because they aren't ASCII letters.

Comment: Can you show the exact code that produces the problem?

Comment: its too long to fit.  but its pretty much stuff like it would say 'til and that apostrophe would cause the error.

Comment: @PythonTrubble, you don't need to provide the exact code, but you need to provide code that demonstrates the exact error.

Comment: And you already tried putting `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of the file, as others have suggested?

Comment: Well now it works but where the apostrophes are, they turn into 3 letters of gibberish.

Comment: @PythonTrubble, ...in that case, you need to use a text editor that understands UTF-8 to write your code, and a UTF-8 terminal when running it. Or just use normal ASCII quotes, rather than the fancy curly variety.

Comment: I am using regular quotes...

Comment: No, you aren't. Note that Microsoft applications replace regular quotes with irregular ones automatically, so this isn't necessarily intentional.

Comment: Then what are the regular quotes? Im just using the ones on the keyboard.

Comment: What text editor are you using? Again, if you're typing into a Microsoft application (or cutting-and-pasting from one), it's replacing the regular quotes with UTF-8 ones automatically, even though you're using the normal keys. Use a sane text editor and that won't happen.

Comment: Im using sublime text 3 and powershell.

Comment: I don't know Sublime Text, so I can't tell you how to turn off Smart Quotes in it. There are plenty of sane editors in the world, though -- emacs, vim, etc. Anyhow -- `”` is **definitely** not a regular quote character. (If you opened a file from Word in Sublime Text, or copied and pasted into Sublime Text from Word, well, there you are).

Comment: Haha but its not the quotes I have a problem with, its the apostrophes.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to replace them all again. It did turn them into the fancy ones..

Answer (score 1):

You mean " or ” ?

Try:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time 
import sys

def delay_print(s): 
    for c in s: 
        sys.stdout.write( '%s' % c ) 
        sys.stdout.flush() 
        time.sleep(0.09999)

delay_print(""" lyrics words bla”h blah blah

""")
```

Comment: For example, Ill put the """ and then on the next line there would be something like 'til and then since its not a ASCII letter, it apparently causes a syntax error.

Comment: Like I suggested above, declaring the encoding will suffice:

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Just try my code above and see if it works.

Comment: but where the apostrophes are it turns them to 3 letters of gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when printing apostrophes and quotation marks, you need to escape them using a backslash, like this: `\"`.

Comment: Please elaborate. Like do I put a \ before every apostrophe?

Comment: Not necessary for the triple-quote form, except when trying to include three quotes next to each other within the contents.

Comment: well now its just the apostrophes are gibberish.